# How to replace close icon on af:dialog adf

Tags: dialog, icons, oracle-adf

How to replace close icon[X] in af:dialog with CLOSE text link.
I know there is a way to hide the icon through css by setting af:dialog-close-region::display: none
but how to replace the icon with CLOSE text.
Am using Jdev version 11.1.1.5.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to switch to another image so you can you replace it with an image of text such as "close".